# How to make “Upload files”selected by default in Insert Media?

Tags: uploads, media

I am frustrated having to click on the "Upload Files" constantly instead of the first choice being Upload Files in posts editor....How can i make “Upload files” selected by default instead of "Media library"?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that you can drag and drop files and initiate upload while in the "media library" panel without having to actually click "upload files" first.

Answer (score 17):

Add this to your functions.php, or preferably a [functionality plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users).

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'media_manager_default' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'media_manager_default' );

function media_manager_default() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults.contentUserSetting=false;
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Damn dude how deep into core did you have to go to pull that one out?

Comment: Changed it to: jQuery(".media-router a:first-child").addClass("active"); jQuery(".media-router a:last-child").remveClass("active"); And it worked (posting here because of request)

Answer (score 4):

If some one it's still looking for a solution, this solution worked for me for all upload images in any post types and on featured images as well:

```
function upload_media_manager_by_default() {
  if ( did_action( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
        wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults.contentUserSetting = false;
        wp.media.controller.FeaturedImage.prototype.defaults.contentUserSetting = false;
      });
    </script>
  <?php
  }
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'upload_media_manager_by_default' );
```